# Website shows "Index of /" page instead of home page, index.php is present

Tags: php, wordpress, apache2

I'm trying to set up a website on Ubuntu with Wordpress. When I try to access the site, it gives me the "Index of /" page which shows the contents of the directory I have the site's config file pointing to.

I've seen other posts with the same question, but they all had their index.php file missing. I can clearly see the index.php file in the directory both in the web browser and in Ubuntu. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Here's a picture of what I see:

[image]

Comment: You need to configure your `DirectoryIndex` setting. See the duplicate thread for details.

Comment: @ceejayoz I did, none of that worked.

Comment: Show us your Apache configuration for the virtualhost in question, then, and make sure you **restarted the Apache server** after making those changes.